# tensorflow kernel code modification

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I want to measure time which is spent in each function.
So I modified tensorflow/core/kernel/conv_ops.cc as below.

```
....
#include <ctime>
....

void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
 // Input tensor is of the following dimensions:
 // [ batch, in_rows, in_cols, in_depth ]
 std::clock_t start;
 double duration;

....
....
....

 duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 std::cout<<"============== conv time : "<<duration<<std::endl;
}

....
....
```

And having saved this code(:wq), I ran a simple cnn tensorflow code. But the code that I added doesn't work(It doesn't show 'cout' result.).

How do I work to show the timing result?

Comment: Do you have an `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: I had tested a user-define operation([hear](https://github.com/davidstutz/tensorflow-cpp-op-example)) but in this code, I add only '#include <ctime>' and it worked well.

Comment: You might need recompile tensorflow?

Comment: can i just use 'cc -c conv_ops.cc' in same directory...?

Comment: Compile conv_ops.cc will not link it to the library. Try recompile the tensorflow and see what happened

Comment: I have searched how to recompile the tensorflow. But I don't know yet hot to do that... TT

Comment: If you just want to see how much time different ops are taking, you can look at the benchmark_tool and how it uses StepStats: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark

Answer (score 0):

Recompile the whole tensorflow project from source using bazel,and a gen_nn_ops.py file would generated from the conv_ops.cc.It may work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LOG(INFO) << "Message";` instead of `std::cout`.

For adding custom operation, [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/custom-op) will help.